# Why ruby kills running threads?

Tags: ruby, ruby-thread

As per thread documentations; when a Ruby program terminates, all running threads are killed, regardless of their states. Why does not ruby waits for all spawned threads to terminate first?

Comment: Because you didn't tell it to using `join`? Show us the minimum code that demonstrates the problem and we'll help pinpoint the exact problem. Without that your question is broad and we can only give broad answers.

Comment: If I compare with Java; where JVM does not get killed after main method is completed; provided running thread are present in memory. So, what might have been reasons to select such a model?

Comment: Why Matz and the architects chose that would best be asked in the Ruby-Talk list where they can explain.